# Linq RemoveAll output?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Is there a way to find out which elements where removed using `RemoveAll()` Linq method?

I want to log which elements were removed if a particular criteria is met.

Comment: @NEBEZ - How? Show us as an answer.

Comment: `RemoveAll` returns count of items removed, not the items.

Comment: `RemoveAll` belongs to `List<T>` class, it isn't a `System.Linq` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RemoveAll` is not a LINQ method, but method defined on particular collection(s?)([`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netcore-3.1) for example). For `List` it accepts a predicate delegate, which you can define as a statement lambda:

```
new List<int> { 1 }
    .RemoveAll(i => 
    {
        var toRemove = true; // your logic
        if (toRemove)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i); // "log"
        }
        return toRemove;
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>.RemoveAll()` doesn't report back *what* it removes, only how many items it removed, so you'll have to write something yourself. So instead of:

```
list.RemoveAll(l => l.Foo == 42);
```

You do it yourself:

```
foreach (var l in list.ToList())
{
    if (l.Foo == 42)
    {
        // log: removing list
        list.Remove(l);
    }
}
```

Or move it into a method and pass that as a predicate:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<string> { "11", "22", "33", "42" };
    
    list.RemoveAll(ToRemove);
    
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
}

private static bool ToRemove(string s)
{
    if (s == "42")
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Removing '{s}'");
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: First suggestion is good, but I think it would throw exception about modifying collection, which is looped over with `foreach`. This is usuallu done with `for(int i = list.Count -1; i >= 0; i--) {}`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn there's a `.ToList()` call to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Keep original list

```
var originalList = list.ToList();
```

2 - Remove items form list

```
list.RemoveAll(u => u.Id == 1);
```

3 - Get removed elements

```
var removedList = originalList.Except(list).ToList();
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the same predicate you pass to RemoveAll to get a list of items:

```
var mylist = new List<thing>();

var itemstoremove = mylist.Where(x=>x.property == "something").ToList();
_logger.LogItems(itemstoremove);
mylist.RemoveAll(x=>x.property == "something");
```

If you want to improve the above code, you could create a predicate and share it between the two operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension method for `List<T>` to help with this, so that you can just pass it a predicate plus a logging `Action<T>` that will get called with each item that's being removed:

```
public static class RemoveAllExt
{
    public static int RemoveWithLogging<T>(this List<T> self, Predicate<T> match, Action<T> log)
    {
        bool matchAndLog(T item)
        {
            if (!match(item))
                return false;

            log(item);
            return true;
        }

        return self.RemoveAll(matchAndLog);
    }
}
```

An example using this to put all the removed items into a separate list:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToList();
var removed = new List<int>();

// Remove all numbers that are a multiple of 3, and put removed items into removed[]:

numbers.RemoveWithLogging(n => n % 3 == 0, n => removed.Add(n));

Console.WriteLine("After removal: " + string.Join(", ", numbers));
Console.WriteLine("Removed items: " + string.Join(", ", removed));
```